# check data exist in table if not than find in another table in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

```
I am using laravel4 .I have three table packages and rates and user_university. Following is column name of three tables
packages -> package_id
         -> university_id
         -> price

user_university ->user_id
                ->university_id

rates    ->rate_id
         ->user_id
         ->price
         ->package_id
```

[image: Packages table]

[image: Rates table]

Here packages is master table and rates is child table. **By default all rates is as per packages but from starting there is no data in rates table if in future there is some  data found in rates table regarding packages(packages_id) then data row fetch from rates table other wise it will take data from packages.**

**Simply if there is package_id found in rate table then row fetch from rate table otherwise it will fetch row from packages.**

I can do this using two query and if else condition but i want know if there one query solution possible or not.

**Need Help .....Thanks**

Comment: Its hard to understand what you need. Can you give the current code so we can help you simplify?

Comment: i think he want to check if in `rates` table `package_id` does exist than that'll fetch particular row from `rates` table other wise it'll fetch row from `packages` table.

Comment: now i want fetch data from two table but condition is if in rate table package id is exist than it will give me data from that table row other wise it will from packages table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [Polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations). It allows to related one table with two tables by single association.